# How do I change the size of an SCNShape?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have a simple `SCNShape` that I want to update based on a user pinch.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0.4, height: 0.4), cornerRadius: 0.02)
let swatchGeometry = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.01428)
let swatchNode = SCNNode(geometry: swatchGeometry)
```

To achieve this, should I do a transformation to the UIBezierPath or is there a property that I can manipulate on the Node or Shape to achieve what I want? I'm only looking to change the width and height of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You have property `scale`:

```
swatchNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5)
```